# Wordpress отображает страницу даже если в url добавить лишние символы, такие как запятая или пробел

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование

При добавлении в url адрес какого-то символа, например запятую, точку или пробел wordpress либо автоматически удаляет этот символ из url и загружает страницу либо просто оставляет этот символ в url адресе и выводит страницу, то есть как-то по умному реализовано что wordpress знает что этот символ лишний и игнорирует его и выводит нужную страницу. Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении любого лишнего символа в url wordpress сразу выдавал ошибку 404, а не догадывался какую страницу ему нужно отобразить?

Comment: ВП всё правильно делает.. Уверен что хочешь поломать этот механизм?

Comment: Проверил на чистой инсталляции: если в урл добавить запятую `/sample-page,/` или `/sample-page/,` - будет 404, вы можете свой пример показать?

Comment: @mihdan да, вот пример сайта https://geekroom.org/product/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0/

Comment: @SeVlad уверен потому что заказчик поставил такую задачу

Comment: Ну, во-первых, тут WooCommerce, а во-вторых, я добавил запятую в урл `/product/комплект-полная-экипировка/,` и меня средиректило на каноникал `/product/комплект-полная-экипировка/`. Вроде всё пока логично

Comment: PS:
Есть два пути ведения бизнеса: клиент всегда прав и клиент всегда НЕ прав. Первый провальный: много ненужных правок за бесплатно. Второй более правильный: в данной ситуации вы - разработчик и специалист в этой области, поэтому условия должны сами диктовать. Если вы делаете разнумные изменения и берете за это деньги - вы делаете правильно.

Comment: @Владимир узнай хотя бы про каноникал что ли. И да, надо научиться объяснять заказчикам их заблуждения. В данном случае (если это и правда работает), то  это не бага а фича, позволяющая не потерять клиентов.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не нужен редирект на канонический адрес и вы хотите, чтобы сразу вываливало 404 ошибка, попробуйте сниппет:

```
function mihdan_stop_404_guessing( $url ) {
    return ( is_404() ) ? false : $url;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'mihdan_stop_404_guessing' );
```

Comment: Все равно если добавить запятую в url или еще какой-то символ, например:
https://geekroom.org/product/kerambit-lege,nda/
https://geekroom.org/product/kerambit-lege&nda/
https://geekroom.org/product/kerambit-lege!nda/
https://geekroom.org/product/kerambit-lege;nda/
Ну и так далее, то товар все равно отображается.
Хотя раньше если добавить какой-то символ в слово product в данном url, то он автоматически удалялся и страница отображалась, сейчас, после вашей функции, при добавлении в product лишнего символа выдает 404, а вот если добавить символ в само название, то товар все равно выводится

Comment: А зачем вы добавляете все эти символы))) Пробую на тестовом окружении - выдает всегда 404 http://screenshot.kobzarev.com/2019-06-26-1561546095.png. У вас установлены плагины какие-то? Сеошные, плагины редиректов, кэш, джетпаки?